# Inconsistent Tomcat response time

Tags: multithreading, performance, tomcat

My Tomcat (8.5.8, behind Apache HTTPD) sometimes (< 1 percent) has high waited time (result from [Glowroot](https://glowroot.org/)).

```
JVM Thread Stats
CPU time: 422.3 milliseconds
Blocked time: 0.0 milliseconds
Waited time: 26,576.0 milliseconds
Allocated memory: 73.3 MB
```

The provided stack trace shows Tomcat was waiting for a latch. At that time my Tomcat host memory, CPU, disk IO, garbage collection looks good.
I tried to issue the same request and same data (compressed size 2.5MB, original size about 25MB) was returned. Most of the times were okay (< 2 seconds) but few times it took long (> 20 seconds).

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeString(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:432)
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._writeStringSegments(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1148)
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2003)
org.springframework.security.web.context.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:540)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:369)
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391)
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:713)
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:808)
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:351)
org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:517)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(AjpProcessor.java:1469)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.access$900(AjpProcessor.java:54)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.writeData(AjpProcessor.java:1353)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:361)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:419)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1259)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:114)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.awaitWriteLatch(NioEndpoint.java:1109)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.awaitLatch(NioEndpoint.java:1106)
java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:277)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

TIMED_WAITING
```

The waiting is due to what reason? Connectivity issue between client? Slow client? Connectivity issue between Apache HTTPD and Tomcat? Not enough file descriptor?

What is the latch at here?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53270016/2834978), looks related to your problem.